# Handling multiple connections using QThreadPool

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, threadpool

Consider a situation where you need to maintain 256 tcp connections with devices just for ocassionally sending commands. I want to do this in parallel(It needs to block until it gets the response), I'm trying to use QThreadPool for this purpose but I have some doubts if it is possible.

I tried to use QRunnable but I'm not sure how sockets will behave between threads (sockets should be used only in thread that they were created in?)

I'm also worried about efficiency of this solution, I would be glad if somebody could propose some alternatives, not necessarily using QT.

Below I'm posting some snippets of the code.

```
class Task : public QRunnable {

    Task(){
        //creating TaskSubclass instance and socket in it
    }

private:
    TaskSubclass               *sub;

    void run() override {
        //some debug info and variable setting...
        sub->doSomething( args );
        return;
    }
};

class TaskSubclass {
    Socket         *sock;           // socket instance
    //...
    void doSomething( args )
    {
        //writing to socket here
    }
}

class MainProgram : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QThreadPool *pool;
    Task *tasks;

public:
    MainProgram(){
        pool = new QThreadPool(this);
        //create tasks here
    }

    void run(){
        //decide which task to start
        pool->start(tasks[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: may i ask why you want to use multiple threads for the solution? Qt's Event system is able to handle hundreds of Tcp connection via one thread without a hassle or does your "socket data handler"-logic blocking the main thread?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just edited post. It needs to block until it gets the response.

Comment: is there a reason why you're not using Signal and slot mechanism? you could just using the readyRead-Signal of the QTcpSocket and connect it to a slot.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but in this solution slots will be executed sequentially, not in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution for this problem is by multiplexing your sockets using `select()`. That way you don't need to create additional threads, and it is a "very POSIX" way to do it.

See for example see this tutorial:

http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/

Or a related question in:

[Using select(..) on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062754/using-select-on-client)

Comment: I would like to keep it on higher level of abstraction preferalby using wrappers like QTcpSockets or boost sockets so i don't need to operate on raw memory.

Comment: After thinking I could take raw descriptors from those wrappes just for the moment of using select() but I would like to make it parallel. It's still good alternative, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

As OMD_AT has allready pointed out the best solution is to use Select() and let the kernel do the job for you :-)

here you have an example of an Async approach and an Syncron multi thread approach.

In this example we create 10 connection to a google webservice and make a simple get request to the server, we measure how long all connections in each approach needed to receive the response from the google server.

**Be aware** that you should use a more faster webserver to make a real test, like the localhost because the network latency has a big impact on the result.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QAtomicInt>

class Task : public QRunnable
{
    public:
        Task() : QRunnable() {}
        static QAtomicInt counter;
        static QElapsedTimer timer;
        virtual void run() override
        {
            QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
            socket->connectToHost("www.google.com", 80);
            socket->write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
            socket->waitForReadyRead();
            if(!--counter) {
                 qDebug("Multiple Threads elapsed: %lld nanoseconds", timer.nsecsElapsed());
            }
        }
};

QAtomicInt Task::counter;
QElapsedTimer Task::timer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    // init
    int connections = 10;
    Task::counter = connections;
    QElapsedTimer timer;

    /// Async via One Thread (Select)

    // handle the data
    auto dataHandler = [&timer,&connections](QByteArray data) {
        Q_UNUSED(data);
        if(!--connections) qDebug("  Single Threads elapsed: %lld nanoseconds", timer.nsecsElapsed());
    };

    // create 10 connection to google.com and send an http get request
    timer.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < connections; i++) {
        QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
        socket->connectToHost("www.google.com", 80);
        socket->write("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
        QObject::connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [dataHandler,socket]() {
            dataHandler(socket->readAll());
        });
    }


   /// Async via Multiple Threads

    Task::timer.start();
    for(int i = 0; i < connections; i++) {
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new Task());
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Prints:

```
Multiple Threads elapsed: 62324598 nanoseconds
  Single Threads elapsed: 63613967 nanoseconds
```

Comment: As I mentioned above in the comments, I would really like to take advantage of many cores in computer, which will be dedicated for this software.

Comment: Is it safe to create socket in main thread and do some operations on it in different one? Also for the sake of efficiency are you able to compare performance of this solution and select() approach? (Is there a big difference)

Comment: yes you're right it's not thread save i have make it thread save... Qt using Select in the Background the main event loop is just sleeping until an event from the kernel is send to the application. if you want to bypass Select you could use synchronous data access like waitForReadyRead() or waitForBytesWritten() aso. and yes in this case you need threads if you're using multiple connections because the thread is blocking...

Comment: Okay, now it is thread safe but isn't it like a normal sequential approach? I don't see the point of using QtConcurrent here because everything (signals and invocation of QtConcurrent) concerning writing and reading to sockets is done within one thread and only handling data can be done concurrently. There is no reason to use QtConcurrent only to handle data in my case. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes right you don't need QtConcurrent, but you can use it to handle the data which you receive in a different thread, that i just wanted to show you... i have added a blocking threaded approach to my example this should be what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Although, the answer is already accepted, I would like to share my)

***What I understood from your question:*** Having 256 currently active connections, from time to time you send a request ("command" as you named it) to one of them and wait for the response. Meanwhile, you want to make this process multithreaded and, though you said "It needs to block until it gets the response", I assume you implied blocking a thread which handles *request-response* process, but not the main thread.

If I indeed understand the question right, here is how I suggest to do it using Qt:

```
#include <functional>

#include <QObject>          // need to add "QT += core" in .pro
#include <QTcpSocket>       // QT += network
#include <QtConcurrent>     // QT += concurrent 
#include <QFuture>           
#include <QFutureWatcher>

class CommandSender : public QObject
{
public:
    // Sends a command via connection and blocks 
    // until the response arrives or timeout occurs
    // then passes the response to a handler
    // when the handler is done - unblocks
    void SendCommand(
        QTcpSocket* connection,
        const Command& command,
        void(*responseHandler)(Response&&))
    {
        const int timeout = 1000;   // milliseconds, set it to -1 if you want no timeouts 

        // Sending a command (blocking)
        connection.write(command.ToByteArray());    // Look QByteArray for more details
        if (connection.waitForBytesWritten(timeout) {
            qDebug() << connection.errorString() << endl;
            emit error(connection);
            return;
        }

        // Waiting for a response (blocking)
        QDataStream in{ connection, QIODevice::ReadOnly };
        QString message;
        do {
            if (!connection.waitForReadyRead(timeout)) {
                qDebug() << connection.errorString() << endl;
                emit error(connection);
                return;
            }
            in.startTransaction();
            in >> message;
        } while (!in.commitTransaction());

        responseHandler(Response{ message }); // Translate message to a response and handle it
    }

    // Non-blocking version of SendCommand
    void SendCommandAsync(
        QTcpSocket* connection,
        const Command& command,
        void(*responseHandler) (Response&&))
    {
        QFutureWatcher<void>* watcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>{ this };
        connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, [connection, watcher] ()
        {
           emit done(connection);
           watcher->deleteLater();
        });

        // Does not block,
        // emits "done" when finished
        QFuture<void> future
            = QtConcurrent::run(this, &CommandSender::SendCommand, connection, command, responseHandler);
        watcher->setFuture(future);
    }

signals:
    void done(QTcpSocket* connection);
    void error(QTcpSocket* connection);
}
```

Now you can send a command to a socket using a separate thread taken from a thread pool: under the hood `QtConcurrent::run()` uses the global instance of `QThreadPool` provided by Qt for you. That thread blocks until it gets a response back and than handles it with `responseHandler` . Meanwhile, your main thread managing all your commands and sockets stays unblocked. Just catch `done()` signal which tells that response was received and handled successfully.

**One thing to note:** asynchronous version sends request only when there is a free thread in the thread pool and waits for it otherwise. Of course, that is the behavior for any thread pool (that is exactly the point of such pattern) but just do not forget about that.

Also I was writing code without Qt in handy so may contain some errors.

**Edit:** As it turned out, this is not thread safe as sockets are not reentrant in Qt.

What you can do about it is to associate a mutex with a socket and lock it each time you execute its function. This can be done easily creating a wrapper around QTcpSocket class. Please, correct me if I wrong.

Comment: Thank you, it looks good but shouldn't there be a problem with thread safety if we pass pointer to socket in QtConcureent.run() ? I heard that sockets are only usable in thread in which they are created and passing them between different threads is not safe (I don't know where sockets should be created then since main thread would be unsafe?). Please correct me if I'm wrong or if you have some explanation that this is safe.

Comment: You are right, it is not thread safe. The reason for that is - sockets in Qt are not reentrant (I forgot, sorry). So I encountered the situation where I try manage sockets connect/disconnect from the main thread and read/write another worker thread. My bad. **But** it leads to the logical conclusion, that **all** operations on a socket must be performed from in same thread no matter what (at least in Qt).